# git annex sync - not pulling in files

Tags: git-annex

I haven't synced my git annex repositories for quite some time and was trying to synchronize them recently, but am getting an error which indicates I need to merge.

I am getting the error: `Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote counterpart.`

I tried to run `git annex merge` and `git pull origin master`, but git complains that I need to run it in a work tree.

[EDIT] I fixed that issue I believe, as my shell command was set to git-shell.  Once I switched to git-annex-shell, it seemed to fix that issue.

Now, I noticed that I have some files missing even after I have done a sync and a get.  I added both repositories to the other so repository A has remote B and repository B has remote A.

However, even after attempting to sync and get several times, I see no changes.  Those files are still missing in one repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around with it more, I  had to reinitialize git and git annex.  It appears to be working as expected now:

git init

git annex init

Once I did that, I could sync and it synced as expected.